# Upgrading MacBook with Crucial RAM sticks

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I have a MacBook Pro mc700 (early 2011), and I've bought a pair of 4Gb Crucial RAM sticks. The problem is that I'm not sure whether these RAM sticks are original or not, and I'm really worried about not being compatible with my MacBook Pro. Can anybody please help me to find out whether is it original or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they physically fit and pass the [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257), they are 100% compatible. Whether they are legit Crucial products is mainly determined by where you purchased them. If you got them online from Amazon or something, they're most likely legit.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there a way to find it out from the barcode on the memory or its serial number or something like that?

Comment: I would contact Crucial Support https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/support-contact and ask them.

Answer (score 3):

The MacBook Pro (MC700) early 2011 supports 1333 MHz PC3-10600 DDR3 SDRAMs. Check the sticker on the RAM-module or on the packaging if it fits. [Here](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Apple/macbook-pro-%2813-inch%2C-early-2011%29) is a link to all compatible modules with product numbers.

If they fit formally and physically put them in and run the Apple Hardware Test/extended memory test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually not I'm not asking about compatibility. I'm looking for a way to find out that these are original Crucial memories or not because I leave in Iran and here is no authorized Crucial store

Comment: @Hamid, in that case (1) you should edit your question to state that explicitly, as I did not find that clear from your question (indeed, your question specifically says you're not sure about compatibility, so it is surprising to see you say that you're not asking about compatibility), and (2) it's probably off-topic here.  Determining authenticity of a product sold by someone other than Apple doesn't sound like a question that fits any of the categories for this site -- have I missed something?  See our [help] for more about this site's focus.